# Show set of elements where sequence of linear operators doesn't converge is dense or empty

Tags: functional-analysis

Let X,Y be normed spaces and $T: X \to Y$ a linear operator.  If $(T_n)$ is a sequence of linear operators also from $X \to Y$ then prove
$$A := \{x \in X : T_nx \not\to Tx \}$$
is dense or empty.

So essentially, I think what I'm supposed to do is to pick an x where there isn't convergence, and so $||T_nx - Tx||> \epsilon$ for the usual ways.  But I'm not sure where to go from here.  If I take a Cauchy sequence around x, this doesn't exactly work because if the $T_n,T$'s are not continuous then the image may not be Cauchy.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

*Hint:* Prove that the complement of any proper subspace of $X$ is dense.

Comment: Thank you, could I ask for another hint on where to begin with that?  Do you mean set-theoretic complement or orthogonal complement?  The reason I'm asking now is that for Hilbert Spaces at least we have a characterization of if the orthogonal complement is null the we have density, but we're not necessarily in a Hilbert space.

Comment: @Michael I think he means set-theoretic compliment. To prove this claim, it suffices to show that for any element of the proper subspace, you can find an arbitrarily close element that lies outside the subspace.

Comment: Yes I meant the set-theoretic complement, thanks @angryavian.

Comment: Thank you both.  I was able to solve it pretty quickly with this help.